# How to keep checkbox state after reload or logout?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a to-do list project and need to save the checkbox state if the user reload the page or logout. I found a solution that keeps the checkbox state after reload which is **localStorage**.

```
    $(function(){
    if (localStorage.input) {
        var checks = JSON.parse(localStorage.input);
        $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', function(i) {
            return checks[i];
        });
    }
});

/* checkbox -- */
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
      var id = $(this).val();
      localStorage.input = JSON.stringify($("input[type='checkbox']").map(function() {
          return this.checked;
      }).get());
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          //data
      } else {
        //error
      }
 });
});
```

But there are 2 problems here: 
1 - When the user logged out the checkbox loses its state even that the database has been updated.
2 - when I I click on a checkbox the same state goes to another user's task, means if user A check the first task 'checked', the first task of user B also takes the same state 'checked'!

Sorry if I didn't explain it well!

Comment: wrong use of `localStorage` . Check out documentation of localStorage https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage` and usage of `sessionStorage` is as below

```
$(function() {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('input')) {
      var checks = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('input'));
      $("input[type='checkbox']").prop('checked', function(i) {
          return checks[i];
      });
  }
});

/* checkbox -- */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
      var id = $(this).val();
      sessionStorage.setItem('input', JSON.stringify($("input[type='checkbox']").map(function() {
          return this.checked;
      }).get()));
      sessionStorage.setItem('input',
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          //data
      } else {
          //error
      })
  });
});
```

Comment: I replaced sessionStorage with localStorage and it worked!. But, Sure this is not a solution that can anyone raly on! If you close the browser or open a new account on the same session it won't work. So any idea how can I do it using server-side?

Comment: server side i don't know, but you can use `localStorage.setItem(userId,"CheckBox Value");` Here `userId` is Unique. This will slove your problem.

Comment: I've fixed the problem by storing the checkbox status in database using PHP. It's more secure than LocalStorage. Your solution solved the problem btw, thanks!

Comment: which one u used `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` ?

Comment: LocalStorage. Because sessionStorage clear the data when the browser closes.